# adding a filter to a angular/jhipster table

Tags: angular, jhipster

I want to add a filter to the MlyCatalogues CRUD table in JHipster.

I add a field  in .html file but I do not know how to proceed>?

Comment: You might want to provide some code of what you've done so far. Please consider creating a stackblitz for this:

https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvpzek

Comment: There are some errors in it that you might want to fix. Please create a minimalist sample that's not dependant on other components.